# Restriction in the context of open balls

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,d')$ be two metric spaces such that $(Y,d')$ is a subspace of $(X,d)$

> since $d'$ is the restriction of $d$, an open ball in $(Y,d')$ is the *restriction* of an open ball in $(X,d)$ to $Y$.

This statement is made in Mendelson's Intro to Topology. «Restriction» used in that special context of open balls is left undefined. Should it be interpreted as if $B(x,\delta )\subset Y$ for some $\delta>0$ then there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\varepsilon)\subset X$ and $B(x,\varepsilon)\cap Y = B(x,\delta)$  ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, he means $$B_{d'}(y, r) = B_d(y,r) \cap Y$$ for all $y \in Y$ and $r>0$. This holds as $y' \in B_{d'}(y,r) \iff d'(y,y') < r \land y' \in Y \iff d(y,y') < r \land y \in Y \iff y' \in B_d(y,r)$ where we use that $d' = d\restriction_{Y \times Y}$.

Comment: Thank you very much !!

Comment: @lou You're welcome..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the textbook but it makes sense to me that he is talking about the hereditary distance. The new distance is just the restriction on  $Y$ -as a function- of your distance on $X$.